# SSL on cloud storage with custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, subdomain, google-cloud-storage, app.yaml

I uploaded my SSL certificate to GAE.  The form is not displaying one of the  sub-domains "images.floridata.com" that is in the certificate.     The other sub-domains that are mapped to ghs.googlehosted.com are present as checkboxes that can be clicked to active the SSL for that sub-domains.  But images.floridata.com which is mapped to c.storage.googleapis.com is not.

We use Google's Cloud DNS.  Can someone tell me how to enable SSL for this subdomain?

If I don't enable SSL on this subdomain will the user get "mixed content" errors?

My site is a Golang app so in my app.yaml file I have a "secure: always" entry - would this prevent images being delivered via http causing "mixed content" errors.

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The "c.storage.googleapis.com" DNS redirect feature does not work for HTTPS addresses. It's HTTP-only.

In order to handle custom domains via HTTPS, you'll need to set up [Google Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/), [register your SSL certificate](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates) with it, and then [configure it to be backed by a GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/using-http-lb-with-cloud-storage).

Answer (score 1):

I fix this problem using **Proxy** on Nginx, Apache or Similar
In my case after 2 weeks testing Firebase and Load Balance I found that solution and work fine to me using HTTPS of my own domain.

https://github.com/presslabs/gs-proxy/blob/master/nginx.conf

Or you can proxy an subfolder using this soltion

```
upstream gs {
    server storage.googleapis.com:443;
    keepalive 128;
}

server {

    ## YOUR CURRENT CONFIG ##

    location ~ /cdn/(.*)$ {

        proxy_set_header    Host storage.googleapis.com;
        proxy_pass          https://gs/BUCKETNAME/subpath/$1;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "";

        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_hide_header       alt-svc;
        proxy_hide_header       X-GUploader-UploadID;
        proxy_hide_header       alternate-protocol;
        proxy_hide_header       x-goog-hash;
        proxy_hide_header       x-goog-generation;
        proxy_hide_header       x-goog-metageneration;
        proxy_hide_header       x-goog-stored-content-encoding;
        proxy_hide_header       x-goog-stored-content-length;
        proxy_hide_header       x-goog-storage-class;
        proxy_hide_header       x-xss-protection;
        proxy_hide_header       accept-ranges;
        proxy_hide_header       Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers    Set-Cookie;
    }

    # location / { ... #
}
```

Depending of your need you must activate Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Cloud Storage.

Proxy is cheap then Load Balance and if you need to SEO is a good choice.

Comment: What nginx instance you use for this (cost) ?

Comment: Onlu install nginx on a cheap instance.

Comment: Can you please share what you did for load balancing?

Comment: I don't did any load balancing, becouse is very expensive, in my laravel / php / nginx instance (Google VM Instance). I configure Nginx to proxy, instead Load Balance, to save money. The code above is Nginx Configuration.